# Background for studying and understanding Stochastic differential equations

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, applications

Assume I have back ground of the following knowledge based on the textbook as :

ODE : [ODE by Tenenbaum](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486649407)

Baby probability : [Ross 's baby probability](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130338516)

Baby real anlysis : [Bartle's introduction to real analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471433314) (1st undergrad course in advanced cal)

Baby measure theory : [Bartle 's element of Lebesgue measure and integration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471042226)

1 course of undergrad linear algebra, and cal 1-3

what specific areas of math would I need to learn more in order to understand the SDE book of Oksendal : [Stochastic Differential Equations: An Introduction with Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540047581) . Many thanks for the suggestion about my background. I will take the 1st graduate course of SDE in the Spring

Comment: Talk to the professor.  That said, my guess is that you should have more or less the requisite background to survive depending on the level of the course.  If the course is more rigorous (which I'm somewhat confident it won't be based on the choice of text) you will need graduate level probability.  Unfortunately, I don't like any of the graduate level probability texts that I have read enough to recommend them.

Comment: That said, it may help to develop some intuition for what is going on.  Brownian Motion is essentially a continuous version of the random walk and a number of the properties of Brownian Motion come from its connection to the Laplacian.  If you want to learn a bit more about that (and refresh on some basic probability that might come up), Greg Lawler has pretty nice notes here: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/reu.pdf

Comment: @Chris:Thanks for the note. So do you think the Oksendal's book is good for SDE beginner ? i.e less rigorous ? I also have a reference of Shreve's stochastic calculus for finance vol 2.

Comment: Shreve and Oksendal are both decent choices for a beginner (I will admit that I like Oksendal more for that purpose) and they are both decidedly less rigorous than genuine stochastic analysis texts.  Neither of them is really a purely computational book, though.

Answer (score 5):

My two cents...

Put aside all the measure/analysis textbooks. When you learnt calculus in college or high-school you did not have to learn analysis right then, isn't it? 
So focus on getting a good understanding of Ito calculus first. 
Focus on being able to compute stuff. 
Pay attention on the "how to" and not on the "why". 
Go to a library and check out these two books:

1. Dynamic Optimization: The Calculus of Variations and Optimal Control 
   By Morton I. Kamien, Nancy L. Schwartz (see last chapters only)
2. The Art of Smooth Pasting By Avinash K. Dixit

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will find the two books, you mentioned. Right now I know that the books I will be used for the SDE is Oksendal and Shreve's stochastic cal II.